# Difficulty translating Python3 get hotp/totp token code to Swift3

Tags: python, swift, security

Recently I found [this awesome 2-factor authentication code generator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169424/2-factor-authentication-code-generator-in-python-3) written in Python 3. I was trying to convert it to Swift 3, but I am having trouble with one specific part, though:

```
def get_hotp_token(secret, intervals_no):
    key = base64.b32decode(secret)
    msg = struct.pack(">Q", intervals_no)
    h = hmac.new(key, msg, hashlib.sha1).digest()
    o = h[19] & 15
    h = (struct.unpack(">I", h[o:o+4])[0] & 0x7fffffff) % 1000000
    return h
```

I so far have only been able to do the first line of the function body :p using code from [here](https://gist.github.com/troupmar/b5bf94be41108a905fcc6a8d09031ced)

```
func getHotpToken(secret: String) -> [Int] {
    let data = secret.base32DecodedData
    <...>
    return theTokens
}
```

I tried reading the documentation on `struct.pack` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) and reading about what packing actually is [here](http://number-none.com/product/Packing%20Integers/index.html), but I still find the concept/implementation confusing, and I have no idea what the equivalent would be in Swift.

According to the documentation, `struct.pack` returns a string in the given format. The format in my case is `>Q`, which means that the byte order is `little-endian` and the C Type is an `unsigned long long`. Again, I am not exactly sure how this is supposed to look in Swift.

... And that is only the second line! I don't really understand how [`HMAC`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html) works (I can't even find the actual 'background' code), so I can't even translate the entire function. I could not find any native library for Swift that has this behavior.

Any pointers or help translating this function will be highly appreciated!

*<sub>P.S. I checked and I think that this is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)</sub>*

Relevant imports:

```
import base64, struct, hmac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished converting my code to Swift 3. This is a little different from the Python version, since this is more of a framework-type thing. It took a lot of experimentation to get the `get_hotp_token` to work (for example the Wikipedia page says it used SHA256 but it actually uses SHA1.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/danielVebman/Totp-Token/blob/master/DigitCode.swift).

When you use this, be sure to add a bridging header with `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>`

Enjoy!